# Console Application return value

Tags: vb.net, console-application, vb.net-2010

I am New in console application .I Need to pass two command line arguments to the console application from a web application and get the returned result from console app.

here I tried in we

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim proc = New Process() With { _
        .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With { _
        .FileName = "C:\Users\Arun\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe", _
        .Arguments = TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text, _
        .UseShellExecute = False, _
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
        .CreateNoWindow = True _
        } _
   }

        proc.Start()

        proc.WaitForExit()
        Response.Write(proc.ExitCode.ToString())


    End Sub
```

my console application code is

```
Public Function Main(sArgs As String()) As Integer


        Return sArgs(0)


    End Function
```

but I can't get the returned value from console app.What is the problem anyone Help?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way in which the parameters are passed to a VB.NET console program (as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2d603cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y550)).

An example:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        For Each arg As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
            Console.WriteLine(arg)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

If you generate a console-project EXE (app.exe) consisting exclusively in the code above and call it (from cmd) like this: `[full_path]app 1 2`, you would get `1 2` printed in your screen.

Thus, all what you have to do is retrieving the arguments from `My.Application.CommandLineArgs`.

-------- UPDATE AFTER THE EXACT REQUIREMENTS HAVE BEEN EXPLAINED BETTER

Under `.Arguments` you have to put just the arguments you want to pass to the console application.

You can return more than just one integer to the calling program by relying on a simple temp file. For example:

CONSOLE PROGRAM:

```
Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("temp")

writer.Write("anything")
writer.Close()
```

CALLING PROGRAM:

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("temp")
Dim line As String
Do
    line = sr.ReadLine() 'reading anything passed from the console
Loop Until line Is Nothing
reader.Close()

Try
   System.IO.File.Delete("temp")
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: then after proc.Start()  ...what code will I write for getting the my console app output

Comment: Depends upon the kind of outputs you expect. A simple integer? Rely on exitcode. That is: Enviroment.ExitCode in the console and proc.ExitCode in the winform.

Comment: Can we return Multiple values from console application?

Comment: The OP wants to *Return* two values from a Console App, not pass to two command line args to it.

Comment: Ah, Sorry. I didn't got that (and wasn't too clear from either your question or your code). So you should change the .Arguments part and put just the argument you want to pass to the console application. What I usually do to return more than one value (or results other than integers) is writing to/reading from a temporary file. The console app writes whatever to the file and the other program reads the file (and deletes it afterwards).

Comment: I have two arguments 100 and 150 and pass this arg in to my console application using vb.net code.. and in console application get this two value and calculate this two value and return back the result.Then in my web app will get the returned value from console app.

Comment: @Arun I have updated my answer. But you should be (much more) clear regarding what you want in order to get a solution quickly and easily. The ideas are pretty simple: pass as many arguments as you wish to the console application by relying on the code you are using (.Arguments part); in the console app get these arguments by using My.Application.CommandLineArgs; to return values, you can rely on Environment.ExitCode for just one integer, otherwise, better create a temporary file (as shown in my updated code).

Comment: Yes I know Sir..  Actually my requirement is ... I have a Web for having two 3 textbox
textbox1=320
textbox2=234

and a button
when click on the button the two values passes to a console application as cmdline arg.And the console app  take this two values in main function and the calculation done there and return the out put to the web app.then the web app will show the result as msgbox.

this is my need ....

Comment: OK. Then: in the web-app code, call the console-app as you are doing in your code (by passing the contents in the two textboxes as arguments); for the console-app, delete your code and emulate the one I wrote (= start a new project as console and write there all the required code to perform all the calculations you wish with the passed arguments, which you can grab by using My.Application.CommandLineArgs). To return the final values you can create a temp file from the console-app (as shown in my code). From your web-app you will read this temp file and thus get the outputs from the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can't natively return two separate arguments, [you are limited A 32-bit signed integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The only way I can think of doing this is if you have two numeric values that you can guarantee are less than 16 bits each then you could combine these into one 32bit value by bit shifting one of them.

This code should get you started:

```
Public Shared Function CombineValues(val1 As Int16, val2 As Int16) As Int32
    Return val1 + (CInt(val2) << 16)
End Function

Public Shared Sub ExtractValues(code As Int32, ByRef val1 As Int16, ByRef val2 As Int16)
    val2 = CShort(code >> 16)
    val1 = CShort(code - (CInt(val2) << 16))
End Sub
```

Usage (console):

```
    'in your console app combine two int16 values into one Int32 to use as the exit code
    Dim exitCode As Int32 = CombineValues(100, 275)
    Debug.WriteLine(exitCode) 'Output: 18022500
```

Usage (Calling code):

```
    'In the calling app split the exit code back into the original values
    Dim arg1 As Int16
    Dim arg2 As Int16
    ExtractValues(exitCode, arg1, arg2)

    Debug.WriteLine(arg1.ToString + "; " + arg2.ToString) 'Output: 100; 275
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is ... I have a Web for having two 3 textbox textbox1=100 textbox2=275and a button when click on the button the two values passes to a console application as cmdline arg.And the console app take this two values in main function and the calculation done there and return the out put to the web app.then the web app will show the result as msgbox. this is my need .

Comment: then just combine my answer with the one given by @varocarbas - that is your solution.